# Samba access outside of subnet

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, samba, file-sharing

I am trying to create a file server that is open to the whole web. It is ultimately to be used as part of a program I'm writing, and it is password protected, so security is not an issue.

To do this, I have shared a folder as I normally would within windows (this uses SAMBA). I can access the share from within the network by running `\\[local IP]` and connecting to it via jcifs within java also works.

I have then set up DMZ in my router. My java client (outside the local network) can recive information from the server (on my local network) so the port forwarding is working. However, as soon as it tries to read a file from the shared folder, it times out. A timeout also occors if I run `\\[public ip]` from the computer outside my local network.

Comment: You are away that the [WannaCry ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack) propagated through SMB, and there are similar exploits for Samba? And the passwords are not particularly strong? If you think security is not an issue, please reconsider. You are essentially setting up a configuration that screams "please attack me!".

Comment: Ok, well, maybe I should rephrase "I'm not very concerned about security". I know that's not a very good approach, but for this use case, there's not much at stake

Comment: Would you mind making the IP address public, so I can hack you? I mean, I could use portscanning or Shodan (and other people *will* do this), but this is less trouble as you are asking for it so nicely... and once I've taken over this server, I'll be in your local LAN, and can take over your other devices at leasure. It's *really* not a good idea. Use something else - web server, even ftp server, whatever.

Comment: this is really more for fun and to see if I can do it than anything else. The other options don't work since I'm using a combination of java/samba. It's as much learning about networking in a fun way as it is actually implementing something